# How to create a circular constrained paddle using Box2D?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am trying to create the ball and paddle setup just like in Circle Pong. It is basically a paddle which revolves about a circular path as if it is tied by a rope to the center of the circular orbit.

[image]

here is a video of Circle Pong: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sitwBolywY

I want to use Box2D for the physics. How do I constrain the paddle to move in a circular orbit? I might even want to have multiple paddles for a circular orbit (with a fixed angular distance from each other).

A distance joint with a static central body won't work because the central body might obstruct / come in the way of the ball. Also it won't work with multiple paddles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

for the first I'm not sure if you need physics engine in game like this at all - it seems to be such simple that simple scene2d actions + setting origins should be enough - please notice that it would improve your game performance and make it easier to deploy.

But - if you are sure you want to use box2d please consider using distance joint with a body **which has a fixture with isSensor = true**. It won't take part in collision calculations, letting you to achieve your point.

```
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = yourMaterial;
    fixtureDef.shape = yourShape;

    fixtureDef.isSensor = true;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! do you have suggestions for implementing two such paddles opposite to each other in the same orbit?